# Is there a time and reason to make a character simplistic?

Tags: characters, character-development

[George Martin said he wants to rewrite Viserys](https://youtu.be/kf7G3n9rqa8?t=991) since in the shows he's more complex and less simplistic than in the books.

That got me thinking whether it makes sense to make a character a lot more simplistic, and if there's a time where such a character might make more sense, or whether it is always better to make them more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not as simple as more complex = better. A character should be complex enough to fit their role/purpose in the story, and the target audience should also be taken into account.

Raskolnikov is a significantly more complex character than Mickey Mouse but then *Crime and Punishment* is trying to do very different things than *Steamboat Willy* and if you tried to put Raskolnikov in Mickey's place it wouldn't make the story better, quite the opposite.

Judging the amount of depth and complexity to give minor characters is perhaps a more difficult task than it is for major ones - you want to give them enough complexity that they seem "real" to the audience but you don't want to bog the audience down with them.

Take Casey Becker from *Scream* - she is a high-school student, she has a boyfriend, she likes scary movies and popcorn. That's about all we know about her - but that's all we *need* to know about her she's in the movie for about 12 minutes before dying and making her more complex would have necessarily taken more time and thus delayed the scene from doing what it was there for in the first place.